# "a half of the troubles" or "half of the troubles"

Tags: articles

> When a car mechanic sees a woman behind the wheel, he finds numerous troubles with the car. But when he sees her husband, **a** half of the troubles disappear without repair.

Is the indefinite article permissible here? It seems to be out of place, but I've read that in most cases "*a half of*" is no worse than "*half of*", so I can't find a justification for the omission of the article.

Comment: No, it is not idiomatic. You'd hear, in the US, most often, "Half the troubles disappear". No "of" either, though "of" is OK.

Comment: @TRomano - this combination seemed better to me too, but I must say I'm not sure how to explain it logically.

Comment: "A half" means a particular half -- as if the troubles had been evenly divided into two sets, the half that remain and the half that disappear; but that isn't really what it means.

Comment: What is the source of your quote?

Comment: @user3169 - It's just an example passage, made up for the occasion. Actually a passage based on one text at lang-8, a proofreading site (a good source of questions on grammar).

Answer (score 1):

A half of the troubles disapear without repair.

Half the troubles disappear without repair.

I think both sentences are grammatically correct. In the first sentence, "half" has been used as a noun, whereas in the latter, it has been used as a determiner. Even it's correct to say "half of the troubles disappear without repair.

The Free Dictionary uses half as a noun in the sentence "A half of the voters have not made up their minds.

Longman Dictionary states the following sentences:

1- Over half of the children live in one-parent families.

2- Only half the guests had arrived by seven o'clock.